# Set Excel to "High Priority" in task manager, still only using 8% CPU

Tags: microsoft-excel, windows-10, cpu

I have a large spreadsheet that I'm performing a sort on.

When I sort one of the columns, Excel says "Not Responding" and about 20 minutes later it finishes processing and is ready again.

I changed the processor priority in the task manager to "High" but it still shows that `EXCEL.EXE` is only using 08% of the CPU. `System Idle Process` is just above it with ~85%.

Can I make Excel use more CPU?  It is the Excel 64 bit install from Office 365.

Answer (score 1):

Excel does not use more than one core by default.

If you have a 6-core CPU with hyper threading, see: [About Excel's "Enable multi-threaded processing" option](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2696967).

From the link above:

> Excel's "multi-threaded processing" option was first introduced in
>   Microsoft Office Excel 2007. The setting is located in Excel Options |
>   Advanced | General. It is enabled by default but must have a capable
>   processor to be utilized. The "Enable multi-threaded processing"
>   setting controls multi-threaded operations other than calculation.
>   These include multi-threaded sort, row height calculations, and
>   finding the best fit for column widths. Additionally: this setting is
>   not available in the Object Model for use in VBA.

Comment: And 100/12 = 8.333.  Neat.  I'll enable the option.

Comment: Wait, the article you linked actually says "It is enabled by default" which I confirmed.  It also says it "controls multi-threaded operations other than calculation. These include multi-threaded sort".  What does this mean?  Why is it still only using 1 core?

Comment: Is the option "use all available processors in this computer" checked?

Comment: It's called `Enable multi-threaded processing`.  I don't see a setting called `use all available processors on this computer`.

Comment: So you don't see something like this?
https://youtu.be/GW3iLbVLHoM?t=1m34s

Comment: Yes, that is under the `Formulas` section.  It is the default value and this setting is specific to calculations.  The checkbox mentioned in the article you linked is under `General` and is also checked by default.